# Problema al insertar valores a nuevos atributos en un JSON

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto con una estructura parecida a la siguiente :

```
    elemento = {
    "Id": 164,
    "Nombre": "WSGEN",
    "Descripcion": "SML"
    }
```

En donde quiero anexarle un nuevo campo denominado "valor", con su respectivo contenido de la siguiente manera:

```
    elemento["valor"]= contenido
```

Lo que espero que suceda es que apareza el nuevo campo con su valor, pero lo que me genera es esto:

```
    elemento = {
    "Id": 164,
    "Nombre": "WSGEN",
    "Descripcion": "SML",
     "valor"=""
    }
```

No entiendo exactamente porque sucede eso, y no se si existe alguna forma alterna de generar el campo con su contenido.

Comment: Que es lo que contiene la variable `contenido`?

Comment: Solo es un string

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un nuevo campo como te lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var elemento = {
    "Id": 164,
    "Nombre": "WSGEN",
    "Descripcion": "SML"
    }
    
    //Puedes agregarlo de la siguiente forma
    elemento.ejemploTexto = "otro";
    elemento.ejemploNumeros = 1231;
        
    console.log(elemento);
```

En tu caso solo debes saber como obtener el valor que deseas de `contenido` y asignarlo a `elemento.valor`.

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de asignar nuevos valores es usando [`destructuración`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) de objetos. En tu caso específico, sería de esta forma:

```js
let elemento = {
    Id: 164,
    Nombre: 'WSGEN',
    Descripcion: 'SML'
};
let contenido = 'El-Contenido';

({ valor = contenido, ...el } = elemento);
elemento = { ...el, valor };

console.log(elemento);
```

O también puedes hacerlo directamente sobre el `elemento`:

```js
let elemento = {
  Id: 164,
  Nombre: 'WSGEN',
  Descripcion: 'SML'
};
let contenido = 'El-Contenido';

elemento = { ...elemento, valor: contenido };

console.log(elemento);
```